# Sliding Menu getting BaseContext

Tags: android, android-context, slidingmenu

I am using [SlidingMenu library](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) provided by jfeinstein10, and I would like to inflate a certain number of linearlayouts with textviews in them ( each linking to one Activity inside my app). I would like to make the textview that starts current Activity be non-clickable, but for this, I have to create a condition where I can compare current Activity's context to the context of the Activity that created this SlidingMenu. I know it sounds quite complicated what I'm trying to explain, but I also feel like the solution could be quite simple. 
I`ll show a picture so you can understand better:

[image]

So I would like, ie Cart textView to be disabled for tapping, if current Activity (the one on the right) is Cart Activity.

I have to do something like this:

```
tv_menu_cart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             // check if Cart Activity's context is the current one and -> do nothing, otherwise continue with starting the activity.

            startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), Cart.class));
            sm.toggle(false);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Why don't you use fragments?

Comment: Actually that SlidingMenu image showed in my post is indeed a fragment, but still what is the right condition I have to create there?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not quite clear to me what content you wrote. But seeing at your title, I guess you are trying to get the context.

If that is what you are looking for, there are few methods you can use:

```
 - getContext() 
 - getBaseContext() 
 - getApplicationContext()
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: on other note, you can get parent Activity by calling [Activity.html#getParent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getParent)

Comment: I edit-ed my question so I would be more clear about what I'm asking about.

Comment: to compare your application contexts, you can first get the parent activity and get its application context like: `activity.getParent().getApplicationContext()` and compare it to the current context.

Comment: it still beats me up.. given the next example: CartActivity extends BaseFragmentActivity, what would be the code for the desired condition inside BaseFragmentActivity class. Compare whom to whom? ( 'this' -> links to BaseFragmentActivity).